# POST form - Select as input only sending first value

Tags: php, html, forms

I have two identical selects, obviously named differently in order to differentiate. When I post the form to my PHP page and echo the value, it always comes out as the first option.

So I can echo type1, and the chosen value will display, but for type2 the value will always be 0.

```
<form action="update.php" method="post" name="tt-upd" id="tt-upd">
    <input name="time1" type="time">
    <select name="type1" form="tt-upd"> 
        <option value="0">0</option> 
        <option value="1">1</option> 
        <option value="2">2</option> 
        <option value="3">3</option> 
        <option value="4">4</option> 
    </select>
    <input name="time2" type="time">
    <select name="type2" form="tt-upd"> 
        <option value="0">0</option> 
        <option value="1">1</option> 
        <option value="2">2</option> 
        <option value="3">3</option> 
        <option value="4">4</option> 
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

I'm pretty lost as I can't see anything different between the two.

Oh and **PHP** code is just

```
echo $_POST['type1'];
echo $_POST['type2'];
```

Update: It's not just taking the first value, regardless of where I place the 0 value in the HTML, it will always echo 0

update.php

```
<?php
include 'dbconnect.php';


echo $_POST['type1'];
echo $_POST['type2'];
$m1 = "";
$t1 = "";

?>
```

dbconnect.php

```
<?php

$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Comment: The second select is always coming out as 0, regardless of what value you choose.

Comment: @SumanDey **but for type2 the value will always be 0.**

Comment: try to check your post variables. `print_r($_POST)`

Comment: I just tried your code, works for me, can you do a `var_dump($_POST)`

Comment: I think you need to have a look at your or share your update.php file. It must be manipulating $_POST['type2'].

Comment: i check this but i get my result

Comment: Array ( [time1] => 12:55 [type1] => 3 [time2] => 00:52 [type2] => 0 [submit] => Submit )

Comment: @ErsinDemirtas - The only other code in update.php is creating variables and connecting to the DB, no relation to the posted variables.

Comment: Still, show your PHP code. Also, try changing the name of your second select tag and try removing the form on your select tag it's not a required option.

Comment: Works fine for me... Nothing wrong with your HTML. I knew that before I tested it though, you're doing something wrong in your PHP code.

Comment: Also, a form should have an ID, not a name... a name is for inputs.

Comment: @hungrykoala Changing the name and removing the form option fixed it! Thank you heaps! Still majorly confused by the cause, but working now!

Comment: @patrick - I did that after the error occured to try fix it. It has been removed from my code already.

Comment: What happens if you test if the values are set first?

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['time1'])) { echo $_POST['time1']; }`  for each of them

Comment: @LoveHateDevelopment No worries. Something might be using your specified name. It's best to use real word names for variables to avoid this kind of scenarios. :)

Comment: @hungrykoala Just tested it. It was definitely in the name, not the form option. That does make sense, I will make sure to use better naming conventions in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by hungrykoala

Issue was due to the name of the select, once changed it worked without error. Full answer in question comments